# trying to pan google sphere with device movement

Tags: javascript, mobile, geometry, device-orientation

I am thinking of panning around a Google Sphere using mobile device movement, similar to what Google Cardboard is doing, but inside a webapp. any libraries you know of? i couldnt find something solid.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla has good documentation about Detecting device orientation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation

It's pretty basic and easy to use.

For your idea you would basically want to have the image of your Sphere inside a relative div with overflow hidden, and make the image move absolutely according to the tilting/accelerating of your device.